# How to to make a SpriteNode rotate in SpriteKit with Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hello guys im coding a game at the moment and I have small problem which I don't understand.

When I press on the SpriteNode I want it to rotate exactly 360 degrees and then stand still. How can I do this? I tried it with M_PI but it doesn't work. Thats how I did it:

```
let rotate= SKAction.rotateToAngle(M_PI, duration: 0.5)
    restart.runAction(rotate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RotateTo will rotate the Sprite to a degree/rad. RotateBy will rotate the Sprite by a certain number of rads/degrees. So to rotate an object 360 degrees use rotateBy and convert 360 to rads.

In your current case you are telling an object currently at rotation 0, which is the same as rotation 360, to rotate to position 360, so it it finishes the action immediately as its already there.

Comment: A positive angle will rotate a node counter-clockwise and `M_PI` (i.e., pi) is 180º not 360º.

Comment: If `zRotation` is 0 and you apply a `RotateTo` `SKAction` with `2*M_PI` as the `radians` parameter, the sprite will rotate by 360º.

Comment: You should provide an answer to the original question then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using rotateByAngle:

```
let rotate= SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 0.5)
restart.runAction(rotate)
```